# hasManyThrough Laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, has-many-through

Given the next models and using Laravel 5.2:

### Entry

- id

### Attribute

- entry_id
- asset_uuid

### Asset

- uuid

---

1. An entry has many attributes
2. An attribute has one asset
3. An asset has many attributes

I would like to make the relation **between Entry and Asset** but I'm not able to do it with **HasManyThrough** since 'an attribute has one asset'. Here the current relations:

**Entry model**

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EntryAttribute::class);
}
```

**Attribute model**

```
public function asset()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Asset::class, 'uuid', 'asset_uuid');
}
```

**Asset model**

```
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EntryAttribute::class, 'asset_uuid', 'uuid');
}
```

Any idea on how could I do the assets relation like:

```
$entry->assets()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plz provide the relationships code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hasManyThrough` in your `Entry` class like the following:

```
public function assets(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Asset::CLASS,
        EntryAttribute::CLASS,
        'entry_id', // Foreign key of your attribute table
        'asset_uuid', // Foreign key of your asset table
        'id', // Local id in your entry table
        'uuid', // Local id in your entry attribute table
    );
}
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: hasManyThrough has changed in newer Laravel versions and allows the params you say. I'm on Laravel 5.2 and I'm only able to set 3 keys, not 4 like you specify

Comment: @suarsenegger You can change your `local id` of your entry table to `id` or update to `5.5`?